# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero during net_segment inference patch aggregation

Tags: niftynet

I ran (on Ubuntu 16.04 in a Google Cloud VM Instance):

```
net_segment inference -c <path-to-config>
```

for a binary segmentation problem using `unet_2d` with softmax and a (96,96,1) spatial window. 
This was after I trained my model for 10 epochs and saved the checkpoint. I'm not sure why it's drawing a zero division error
from `windows_aggregator_resize.py`. What is the cause of this issue and what can I do to fix it?

Here are some inference settings and the corresponding error:

```
pixdim: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

[NETWORK]
batch_size: 1
cutoff: (0.01, 0.99)
name: unet_2d
normalisation: False
volume_padding_size: (96, 96, 0)
reg_type: L2
window_sampling: resize
multimod_foreground_type: and

[INFERENCE]
border = (96,96,0)
inference_iter = -1
output_interp_order = 0
spatial_window_size = (96,96,2)
```

---

```
INFO:niftynet: Accessing /home/xchaosfailx1/niftynet/models/MSD/heart_la_seg/models/model.ckpt-10 ...
INFO:niftynet: Restoring parameters from /home/xchaosfailx1/niftynet/models/MSD/heart_la_seg/models/model.ckpt-10
INFO:niftynet: Cleaning up...
WARNING:niftynet: stopped early, incomplete loops
INFO:niftynet: stopping sampling threads
INFO:niftynet: SegmentationApplication stopped (time in second 17.07).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/bin/net_segment", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/__init__.py", line 139, in main
    app_driver.run_application()
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/application_driver.py", line 275, in run_application
    self._inference_loop(session, loop_status)
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/application_driver.py", line 493, in _inference_loop
    self._loop(iter_generator(itertools.count(), INFER), sess, loop_status)
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/application_driver.py", line 442, in _loop
    iter_msg.current_iter_output[NETWORK_OUTPUT])
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/application/segmentation_application.py", line 390, in interpret_output
    batch_output['window'], batch_output['location'])
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/windows_aggregator_resize.py", line 55, in decode_batch
    self._save_current_image(window[batch_id, ...], resize_to_shape)
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/windows_aggregator_resize.py", line 82, in _save_current_image
    [float(p) / float(d) for p, d in zip(window_shape, image_shape)]
  File "/home/xchaosfailx1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/niftynet/engine/windows_aggregator_resize.py", line 82, in <listcomp>
    [float(p) / float(d) for p, d in zip(window_shape, image_shape)]
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

For reproducing the error:

- changed the padding in `niftynet.network.unet_2d.py` from `valid` to `same`
- dataset [Task2_Heart] : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HqEgzS8BV2c7xYNrZdEAnrHk7osJJ--2
- updated config: 
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RI111BZLv4Lhf9cGvHo_sAHRt_k5Xt0I

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check the inference data but I think `spatial_window_size` in `[INFERENCE]` should be `96, 96, 1` as that's what you set in training.

Comment: Then it looks like a voxel size resamplling issue, how about leaving `pixdim=` as empty value?

Comment: Still draws the error (I retrained the model with the new config and did `net_segment inference` with that checkpoint). Is it bad that after the `SegmentationApplication` (for training) stopped, it says: `terminate called without an active exception Aborted (core dumped)`?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that I made was that I set the border (96,96,0) under `[Inference]` to the same shape as my spatial window (96,96,1), so when the batch was cropped in `decode_batch`, the cropped image had an image shape with 0s in it. Hence, when the zoom ratio was calculated in `_save_current_image`, it led to a ZeroDivsionError. The temporary fix was to remove volume padding and changing the `border=(0,0,0)`.